# Wifi password changed. How do I change it on my computer so I can access it?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

Win XP Pro, SP3.

I have access to wi-fi where I live. The administrator changed the password for access and gave me the new password.

However, I don't know how to change the password on my computer.

I have searched using many terms, but everything I find tells me how to make the change at the router. As I say that's already been done.

How can I change the password in my computer to access the net again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XP Start-> Connect to ->Show all connections
(By default it "connect to" option wont display. To enable this, Right click on Taskbar,click properties,click start menu tab,press customise button,then click Advanced tab and scroll down the start menu items choose the "Display as connect to Menu" radio button . Now click ok and apply.)

Now its will shows you all network adaptors like LAN,Wifi,Blutooth,etc.,

Right click on the wirless network connection ,Click properties,now tick the chekbox "Show icon in the notification area when connected "

Now refresh your network list available or search a network ,If the network is security enabled means it will promt you to enter the password or key given by your network manager.
Thats it .
If you have any doubts feel free to ask me.I will help you by providing screenshots.

Comment: +1. Thank you, I had discovered this. I am not sure that it will remember this password, and am too bust right now to shut down my computer. Do I have to do this every time I log on, or will it remember the new password?

Comment: While entering your security key or password you will be prompt to enter twice in the first time, then tick the check box "remember my password" option.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the saved wireless network from your machine, and then re-scan and re-enter the new, correct credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the wifi icon (usually shows as bars) on the task bar and open the network manager. Right click on the ssid, choose security and change the password.

Comment: Thanks, but no wifi icon. How else can I find the network manager? If I go to properties for my connection and go to the ssid page, there is no way to add or change a password, so I must be in the wrong place.

Comment: I think I found out how to add the icon. I remember I removed it some time ago. I am not at mu location now, but will try it when I am. Thanks.

Comment: On Windows 7  Control Panel ->Network and sharing -> Manage wireless Networks -> Right click SSID -> Click Properties -> Click Security tab -> Network Security Key

Comment: Thank you, I had tagged it as XP but it wasn't obvious enough. Can you advise on the routine for XP? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more apparent.